# Calling make with mingw-w64

Tags: makefile, mingw-w64

I’m trying to compile an application using [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/).

My operating system is macOS Catalina.

mingw-w64 is installed using Homebrew (`brew install mingw-w64`).

First I define which compiler to use, like this:

`export 'CC=/usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc'`

Now I wonder how I should call make.

Should I call it like this:

`CC="$CC" make -f ./makefile.foo`

Or should I call it like this?

`make -f ./makefile.foo CC="$CC"`

Comment: I would expect that both would work.

Comment: @ssbssa they yield totally different results though :)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the application I’m trying to compile is Info-Zip 3.00 https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/Zip%203.x%20%28latest%29/3.0/zip30.tar.gz/download